# How to slowly draw a circle in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, geometry

I want to slowly draw a circle in pygame so the act of drawing is actually visible to the naked eye. I got a function on stackoverflow to draw a straight line by incrementing the end point and keeping the starting point same but couldn't figure out how to slowly draw a circle in the pygame screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can use the standard sine and cos circle formula:

- `x = r * cos(radians(i)) + a`
- `y = r * sin(radians(i)) + b`

Where `a` is the `x` coordinate of the center of the circle, and `b` is the `y` coordinate of the center of the circle
`r` is the radius of the circle.

To slow down the animation, use a `Clock` object. You can access the functions `sin` and `cos` from the built-in `math` module *(note that you'll need to pass in the values as radians, hence the importance of the `radians` function)*.

#### The implementation:

```py
import pygame
from math import sin, cos, radians

pygame.init()
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

r = 100
a = 300
b = 200

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
for i in range(1, 361):
    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.draw.circle(wn, (255, 255, 255), (int(r * cos(radians(i)) + a), int(r * sin(radians(i)) + b)), 2)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Output:

[image]

If you prefer to use standard lines as the outline instead of overlapping dots, use the [`pygame.draw.line`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line) function like so:

```py
import pygame
from math import sin, cos, radians

pygame.init()
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

r = 100
a = 300
b = 200

def x_y(r, i, a, b):
    return (int(r * cos(radians(i)) + a), int(r * sin(radians(i)) + b))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
for i in range(0, 360, 2):
    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.draw.line(wn, (255, 255, 255), x_y(r, i, a, b), x_y(r, i+1, a, b), 2)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the turtle library because it contains a circle function. For example circle(40) would draw a circle with a radius of 40 units. When you run the program the circle will be drawn in front of you

Comment: Hello! When a question asks how to do sth with a module, suggesting a solution using another module is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states your main aim is to just draw a circle, so I would suggest you to consider using turtle.

You can run these codes and get the output:

```
import turtle
  
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.circle(50)
```

Comment: Will it run on the pygame screen?

Comment: The above answers will create a different turtle screen and will draw a circle there.

Comment: Hello! When a question asks how to do sth with a module, suggesting a solution using another module is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((626, 416))

pygame.draw.circle(screen, (r,g,b), (x, y), R, w)
running = True
while running:
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
```

This is how you can draw a circle on a pygame screen with `(r, g, b)` as color, `(x, y)` as center , `R` as radius and `w` as the thickness of the circle.

Comment: I'm sorry, this does not do what the OP specified.